# Cyrillic in glossary/acronym entry

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, cyrillic

I want to define acronyms and terms in Bulgarian. Unfortunately, when I do so, LaTeX gives a whole lot of errors and do not compile. Anything to help?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\inputencoding{cp1251}
\usepackage[makeindex,acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[dvipdfm,unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{SVN}{SVN}{Apache Subversion Control}
%\newacronym{БДЖ}{БДЖ}{Българска държавна железница}
\begin{document}
\gls{SVN}
%\gls{БДЖ}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\glossarystyle{altlistgroup}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

When you remove the ''%'' from the comments you will see what am I talking about (I have commented the entry and citation of the Bulgarian acronym)

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues here:

1. Glossary labels can't contain active characters (non-Latin characters, including accented letters such as é, are all active). This is because the label is used to define various control sequences used to store the glossary information.
2. Older versions of `glossaries` had a problem with fragile commands in  fields such as `text`. This can be overcome by upgrading to the latest version of `glossaries` (v4.01 at time of writing).
3. `makeindex` isn't designed to work with non-Latin characters. You can use `xindy` instead, but you need to use the `xindy={glsnumbers=false}` package option for non-Latin languages.

Minimal example (requires `glossaries` v4.01 and `xindy`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}

\usepackage[xindy={glsnumbers=false},acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{SVN}{БДЖ}{Българска държавна железница}

\begin{document}
\gls{SVN}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setglossarystyle{altlistgroup}

\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

(You'll need to redefine `\acronymname` to the appropriate translation, see the section "[Changing the fixed names](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:fixednames)" in the `glossaries` user manual.)